# Google Apps Script toolbar debug, run and triggers icons

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, icons

I need help, I have no idea on how I changed the icons showing for debugging and running and now they don't show properly...[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJWIp.png)

Thanks

Comment: It could be a conflict with one of your browser extensions, or you may need to close your browser and reopen it.  Other than that, I don't know of anything that could cause the graphics in those button to be distorted.

Comment: Saddly I've restarted browser, clear all history data (incluying cookies and history) with no success but thanks

Comment: This is the url for the sprite that contains these images [http://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/ide/v2/sprite11.png](http://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/ide/v2/sprite11.png)

Comment: I also notice a similar condition as shown on your example when I zoom my browser to zooms greater than 150%.

Comment: It actually was part of zooming in too much!!! thanks :)